# Memory usage difference between Windows and Ubuntu for a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As the title says, I'm seeing a big difference between the memory usage of a numpy array between Windows and Ubuntu.

Here's a simple code to replicate this issue:

```py
import numpy as np
import joblib

a = [1]*1000
b = [a for i in range(1000)]
np_arr = np.array(b)

joblib.dump(np_arr, 'arr.h5')
```

If I run this code in a Windows 10 machine, `arr.h5`'s size is **3907KB**.

But it I run this on Ubuntu 18.04, it's **7812KB**

The main issue is that I'm dealing with large datasets and my code runs fine on a Windows machine with 16GB, but I'm having Memory Errors on Ubuntu with 32GB

Comment: Is it possible that your Windows Python is compiled as a 32-bit application?

Comment: Both are 64-bit Python installations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep this is a difference between Windows and Linux...

The default integer in numpy is `np.int_` which maps to a C `long`, [see docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/user/basics.types.html). The C standard doesn't specify the size of a `long` exactly, just that it's [at least 32 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) (4 bytes). The actual size depends on the [compiler and cpu architecture](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os). There's already a discussion of this issue on the [numpy bug tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9464).

The problem can avoided by explicitly setting the integer type:

```
np_arr = np.array(b, dtype=np.int32)
```

If you know the smallest and largest value that your array will hold, you can potentially get away with choosing a smaller integer type, like for example int16 or uint8.